# Why isnt this test passing?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I made a test to update the user changeset that should pass with invalid data, but the validation of the user aren't allowing it to pass , sorry if this is noob, im just starting at elixir

```
   test "renders errors when data is invalid", %{conn: conn, user: user} do
      assert conn = put(conn, Routes.api_user_path(conn, :update, user), user: @invalid_attrs)
      assert json_response(conn, 422)["errors"] != %{}
    end
  end
```

The output

```
** (Ecto.InvalidChangesetError) could not perform update because changeset is invalid.

     Errors

         %{
           email: [{"can't be blank", [validation: :required]}],
           name: [{"can't be blank", [validation: :required]}],
           password: [{"can't be blank", [validation: :required]}],
           password__confirmation: [{"can't be blank", [validation: :required]}]
         }

     Applied changes

         %{is_active: nil}

     Params

         %{
           "email" => nil,
           "is_active" => nil,
           "name" => nil,
           "password" => nil,
           "password__confirmation" => nil
         }

     Changeset
Thats all lines been used

         #Ecto.Changeset<
           action: :update,
           changes: %{is_active: nil},
           errors: [
             name: {"can't be blank", [validation: :required]},
             email: {"can't be blank", [validation: :required]},
             password: {"can't be blank", [validation: :required]},
             password__confirmation: {"can't be blank", [validation: :required]}
           ],
           data: #TrelloClone.Auth.User<>,
           valid?: false
```

```
   @invalid_attrs %{name: nil, email: nil, is_active: nil,password: nil,password__confirmation: nil}


def update(conn, %{"id" => id, "user" => user_params}) do
    user = Auth.get_user!(id)

    with {:ok, %User{} = user} <- Auth.update_user(user, user_params) do
      render(conn, "show.json", user: user)
    end
  end


  def update_user(%User{} = user, attrs) do
    user
    |> User.changeset(attrs)
    |> Repo.update!()
  end


 def get_user!(id), do: Repo.get!(User, id)
```

Thats all lines been used, obs: they are in different files, Auth is the context of User

Comment: Can you show what @invalid_attrs is as well as your code in the controller to update a user?

Comment: i will put at the post

Comment: Use `update` not `update!` in your `update_user` function.

Comment: Your `@invalid_attrs` map uses atom keys (e.g. `%{id: nil}`, but your `update` function requires pattern-matching on string keys, e.g. `%{"id" => id}`.  Is that part of what's going on here?
Can you paste in the changeset functions from your User module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, [`Repo.update!`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html?#c:update!/2) you use in `update_user/2`

> Same as [`Repo.update/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:update/2) but returns the struct or **raises if the changeset is invalid**.

The exception is raised on the invalid changeset and your test blows up. If you want to indeed *raise* on incorrect inputs, you might amend the test with [`ExUnit.Assertions.assert_raise/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.Assertions.html?#assert_raise/2)

```rb
test "renders errors when data is invalid", %{conn: conn, user: user} do
  assert_raise  Ecto.InvalidChangesetError, fn ->
    put(conn, Routes.api_user_path(conn, :update, user), user: @invalid_attrs)
  end
end
```

But since you want to display `422`, you’d better off with using `Repo.update/2` in `update_user/2`

```rb
def update_user(%User{} = user, attrs) do
  user
  |> User.changeset(attrs)
  |> Repo.update() # not Repo.update!()
end
```